# What does determine scalar/list context of `split`?

Tags: perl, split

According to [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod), the goatse operator `=()=` provides a list context so that it can count the number of its elements.  I used to think that too.  But when I accidentally use the operator along with `split`, I noticed something strange.

The first two lines of following, are exact same statements written in `Effective Perl Programming, 2nd edition`.  But as a matter of fact, it seems `split` changes behavior by the left side.

```
my $wc;
$wc = () = "foo:bar:buz" =~ m/(\w+)/g;  # => 3
$wc = () = split /:/, "foo:bar:buz";   # => 1

$wc = (undef) = split /:/, "foo:bar:buz";   # => 2
$wc = (undef, undef) = split /:/, "foo:bar:buz";   # => 3
$wc = (undef, undef, undef) = split /:/, "foo:bar:buz";   # => 3
```

Could someone tell me what makes the changes of return values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's documented in [split](http://p3rl.org/split) further down where LIMIT is discussed:

> when assigning to a list,
>               if LIMIT is omitted (or zero), then LIMIT is treated as though it
>               were one larger than the number of variables in the list;

It's an optimization so Perl doesn't create values it would then throw away immediately. Just imagine `$varX` instead of `undef`.

To avoid this optimization, specify a limit of -1:

```
$wc = () = split /:/, "foo:bar:buz", -1;
```

because

> If LIMIT is negative, it is treated as if it were instead
>               arbitrarily large; as many fields as possible are produced.